# Missing Updates on Observers?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript-framework, ember-data

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt7uy/2/)

The template has several instances of the same subView with different bound properties. You can see when those bound properties trigger an event on their observers. Note that subViews A and D trigger, but B and C never do.

```
{{view App.SubView identifier="A" modelDataBinding="view.person.first"}}
{{view App.SubView identifier="B" modelDataBinding="view.person.children"}}
{{view App.SubView identifier="C" modelDataBinding="view.person.children.@each.name"}}
{{view App.SubView identifier="D" modelDataBinding="view.person.children.length"}}
```

So, 2-part question:

1. Why don't B or C ever fire?
2. What would be the proper way to bind to the children of this Person model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed 2 things here: bindings are not the same as observers. You can't bind to something.@each.name, you need to bind to the array and observe on @each. Binding is a connection between 2 values and @each is not really a value, it's a special syntax to tell observers (or computed property dependencies) that you would like to depend on a property on each of the elements in collection.

The other problem is that if you add an observer after a value is set, it will not fire, because the value is already set (ie. there is no change). In your example App.Person.find(1) returns object immediately and person.children does the same - it returns array immediately, which will be later filled with data. So at the point when you run addObserver, children is already set, only its contents will going to be changes (this is why the length observer fires properly).

Here is the fiddle with a few changes: http://jsfiddle.net/drogus/6EVty/1/ (I added observerPath and set person after view is inserted), the code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main">
    {{view App.SubView identifier="A" modelDataBinding="view.person.first"}}
    {{view App.SubView identifier="B" modelDataBinding="view.person.children"}}
    {{view App.SubView identifier="C" modelDataBinding="view.person.children" observePath="modelData.@each.name"}}
    {{view App.SubView identifier="D" modelDataBinding="view.person.children.length"}}
</script>
```

And the view class:

```
SubView: Ember.View.extend({
    init: function( ) {
        this._super();
        var observePath = this.get('observePath') || 'modelData';
        this.addObserver( observePath, this, function( ) {
            document.write( 'trigger ' + this.get( 'identifier' ) + ': ', this.get( 'modelData' ), '<br />');
        });
    }
})
```